# CanCan + Factory_Girl - strange behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot, cancan

I have a two factories - User and Company.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "user#{n}@exyzample.com" }
    password "secret"
    password_confirmation "secret"
  end

  factory :customer, :parent => :user do
    role "customer"
  end

  factory :company do
    name "User Company"
    association :user, :factory => :customer
  end
end
```

Then, when I create company from factory - all is perfect, record saved to database and associated to user. Cool, but when Im trying to test user abilities - all my tests falls.

There is an example (rails console):

```
company = Factory(:company)
=> COMMIT
Ability.new(company.user)
=> Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
```

But

```
company.user 
=> #<User id: 1, email: "user1@example.com", ..., role: "customer">
```

And

```
Ability.new(User.find(1))
=> #<Ability:0xcf6771c> ...
```

I'm confused. Any ideas?